# Kubespray etcdctl: "Error: client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubespray

Configuring Kubespray on 4 nodes, with 2(node1, node2) master nodes and installing etcd on node1 node2 node3, and node3-4 are worker nodes.

I get this following error,

```
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 8, "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/etcdctl --no-sync --endpoints=https://x.x.x.x:2379,https://x.x.x.x:2379,https://x.x.x.x:2379 cluster-health | grep -q 'cluster is healthy'", "delta": "0:00:00.023138", "end": "2020-06-05 17:07:03.033707", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-06-05 17:07:03.010569", "stderr": "Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: dial tcp x.x.x.x:2379: connect: no route to host\n; error #1: EOF\n; error #2: dial tcp x.x.x.x:2379: connect: no route to host\n\nerror #0: dial tcp x.x.x.x:2379:
```

Could someone please explain me what I am doing wrong here while configuring these nodes?

Comment: Can those etcd hosts talk to each other? Any firewalls? Are those ports open on those hosts?